# Catching an exception of an invalid Base64 length

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I am trying to write an exception code, where I try catch the exception (of invalid `Base64` length) and make the program ignore it by not doing the next operation, until it is in proper length. Anyway I can do that?

Here's what I get as a result of the exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in
>   mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

Comment: What does your try/catch look like?

Comment: I don't have one as of yet as I am clueless. My purpose is to prevent the program decrypting a cipher string until a valid length of Base64 has been reached.

Comment: It is a GIGO problem, garbage in - garbage out.  Repeatedly trying doesn't turn garbage into gold.

Comment: The program tries to decrypt an invalid Base64 string but it throws an exception, how do I go about doing this without it throwing an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the best piece of code, but it should do the job, any way you should consider changing your logic as exceptions are not meant to be used for this

```
    bool handled = false;
    do
    {
       try 
       {
          /// your code goes here
          if (decrypted)
             handled = true;
       }
       catch(FormatException e)
       {
       }
    } while (!handled)
```

In your case this will not work. You need to modify the `cipherString.Text` or wait for another user input. So you can try the following:

```
    private void decryptButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string dPassphraseText = dPassphrase.Text;           

            bool decrypted = false;            
            try
            {
                byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherString.Text);
                /// your code goes here
                if (sameKey == true)
                {
                    //your code
                }
                else
                {
                   //your code
                }

            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                  //notify the user somehow, so that he will try to enter passphrase again
            }            
    }
```

Comment: How do I go about using this code, do I enter it within where it says decrypted or above the if code?

Comment: You enter your decryption code there, yes. You should also check somehow if it was successful to stop the loop

Comment: No unfortunately it doesn't stop the loop, suggestions?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/szjUpZMF

Comment: So where is the piece of code I suggested in your code?

Comment: This problem occurs in the decryption stage, @ decryptButton_Click on line "byte[] cipherTextBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherString.Text);"

Comment: Woops, I added the wrong code, here's the new one... http://pastebin.com/h6iQgRxY

Comment: You need to put the code which throws the exception inside a `try-catch` block. And you're not assigning `true` to `handled` variable at all. If only this lines throws the exception, you can put `handled=true` after it. I will update my answer

Comment: Ah, wait a moment. You're not changing the `cipherString.Text` anyhow. Are you waiting for another user input and want to notify him?

Comment: Yes, I am expecting a user to input an encrypted string (valid Base64 length) and automatically decrypts it, the cipherString.Text is not, anyhow, in a stream.

Comment: @SergeantSerk I've updated my code. You don't need a loop here, you need to catch the exception and tell the user that his input was bad and that he should try again

Comment: Thank you very much, worked perfectly, spot on!